Will locked away in a dead person’s house
A dear friend of mine obtained all of my legal information and made a will naming me her executor and sole beneficiary. Unfortunately, she died in her home in Mesa, Arizona, and her will was left in her locked house. What can I do to get the will out of her home so legal proceedings can begin?

Are there any other people involved in the inheritance who would contest your access?

Do you know who has the keys?

No. And no one has the keys.

Talk to the attorney who drafted the will, and if you don't know who that was, find an attorney to help you with the legal process to get access to the house to get the will.

It is relevant if the body is still in the house or not.

You have a few options.
Option One
One, if you know who is the personal representative (a.k.a. executor) named in the will (and the question says that you do), the personal representative has certain powers before actually being appointed that apply retroactively:

Arizona Revised Statutes 14-3701. Time of accrual of duties and powers
The duties and powers of a personal representative commence on
appointment. The powers of a personal representative relate back in
time to give acts by the person appointed which are beneficial to the
estate occurring prior to appointment the same effect as those
occurring thereafter. Prior to appointment, a person named personal
representative in a will may carry out written instructions of the
decedent relating to the decedent's body, funeral and burial
arrangements. A personal representative may ratify and accept acts on
behalf of the estate done by others where the acts would have been
proper for a personal representative.

This authority would probably extend to breaking into the house to get the will and stabilize the situation in the house. Of course, if you can't find it in the house, you have a problem.
Option Two
Another option is to have an intestate estate opened, as if there was no will, with the person entitled to priority in the absence of the will appointed as personal representative (a.k.a. executor). See Arizona Revised Statutes § 15-3203. Then, amend the petition in the case if a will is found to reflect the fact that a will is discovered.
But, this may require the cooperation of family if you are only a friend, and that may pose a sticky situation if the family is not cooperative. This would take several days (after the mandatory 120 hour waiting period from the time of death).
Still, there is some protection in this scenario because anyone finding a will of a deceased person has a legal duty to present it to a court. Arizona Revised Statutes § 15-2516.

Custodian of will; duties; liability
A. After the death of a testator and on request of an interested
person, a person having custody of a will of the testator shall
deliver it with reasonable promptness to a person able to secure its
probate or, if none is known, to an appropriate court.
B. A person who wilfully fails to deliver a will as required by this
section is liable to any person aggrieved for any damages caused by
this failure.
C. A person who wilfully refuses or fails to deliver a will after
being ordered by the court in a proceeding brought for the purpose of
compelling delivery is subject to penalty for contempt of court.

Option Three
A third option would be to bring a "petition for formal probate" alleging that you have copy of the will, and that there is good cause why the original can't be produced at this time. But this would probably take several weeks and an evidentiary hearing, and isn't a sure thing. This is because a will is like a dollar bill, a copy isn't as good as the original. If an original will can't be located, there is a strong, but rebuttable, presumption that the will was revoked by physically destroying it.
Option Four
Arizona is actually one of the only U.S. states that allows for electronic wills, but it is unlikely that your deceased friend had one. But, if you had an electronic copy of an electronic will for your friend, that would solve the problem.
Option Five
It is relevant if the body is still in the house or not.
If the body is or might be in the house, the police can enter to make a welfare check and the corner can enter to deal with the body. Either of these officials might let you gain entry to the premises, even though they have no duty to do so.

Thank you. You’ve provided very good information. Of course the body is not in the house. But now i have a new problem: A out-of-state nephew the decedent had no contact with (in decades) has somehow pushed probate through and taken possession of all of the decedent’s estate. He hired a cleaning company to empty the decedent’s house, and he says no will was found. I do not have the funds to hire an attorney. I’ve applied for a copy of the court proceedings.

I don't know how that is in the US, but in Europe, if it is assumed (or even certain) that somebody is lying dead in a house, one must call the police. They will open the door (by force, if needed). They then call a doctor to confirm the death. If in doubt, they will start an investigation whether the death was natural, too.
If the person is really deceased, the police will try to find out whether he has written a will and whether he has any still living relatives. There are special government jobs taking care of this. Obviously, their task will be simplified if they know that a will exists and that you are the beneficiary. So if you just call the police at the location of the deceased's last living place, they will most likely help you out.

Thank you. We’ve been through all you’ve written about. The police will not help. It’s a conundrum.

Can somebody explain the down votes, please?

@J.Rich What did they say? If nobody entered the house, how would you know she's dead?

The police broke into her house and the medical examiner took possession of her body. I am trying to find out how to determine which attorney crafted her will. Her house was emptied out and I assume the will was discarded.

@J.Rich Understood. You should have included this in the question, as it makes clear that this has apparently happened some time ago.

I suspect the reason for the downvotes is that this is law.stackexchange and this answer isn't based on law. It's just practical advice which is not even based on any certainty ("they will most likely help you out") plus it contains an assumption that this is how it works throughout Europe (which tends to suggest that the answer is just your opinion and not based on any authoritative legal source). A proper answer to OP's "what can I do to get the will out of her home?" would be to set out what legal rights OP can enforce to obtain the will, plus a jurisdiction tag if it's not Arizona law.

@j.rich: In the original question, you said you believe the will is still locked inside her house. Now you say you believe it was discarded. Which is it? Who emptied out the house, and how did they get in?

I just found out (on July 7) that the estate has gone through probate because I found out the decedent’s house is for sale. The real estate agent told me what has transpired.

You are correct, PMF. I should’ve noted that the decedent’s body was discovered on 01/27/24. I’ve been going ‘round and ‘round with Maricopa County government entities without success. It’s extremely frustrating.
